# Cannot find the process which uses most memory

Tags: process, memory

The result of `free -g`:

```
# free -g
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:              62          38          14           7           9          10
Swap:              0           0           0
```

So I check `top`, and press `m`, but still can not find any process using most memories.

```
  PID USER      %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 3792 root      0.0 580:46.07 statmon
18361 root      0.1 282:01.20 sssd_nss
11981 root      0.0   0:08.87 top
18359 root      0.0 151:56.62 sssd_be
    1 root      0.0  36:01.53 systemd
    2 root      0.0   0:01.99 kthreadd
    3 root      0.0   0:00.00 rcu_gp
    4 root      0.0   0:00.00 rcu_par_gp
    6 root      0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H-kblockd
```

Comment: What's the output of `mount | grep tmpfs` ?

Comment: Can you post the output of cat /proc/meminfo ?